# Dynamically Modify $.post url

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, dynamic

Can a `$.post` mirror the `action=''` of a form?

I don't want to make multiple `$.post` functions, but the `action=''` changes as a user selects what he/she wants to submit in the menu system. So, all I would need is one `$.post` function if the url changes dynamically with the `action=''` does.

```
$("#txtrform").submit(function(){

    $.post('{*ACTION*#txtrform}', $("#txtrform").serialize(), function(data) {
        $("#col3").load("/include/txtrpbox/feed.php");
        $('input#txtrinput').val('');
    });

    return false;       
});
```

Comment: You can make use of jQuery's `.attr()` method. `$("#txtrform").attr('action');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#txtrform").submit(function(){

    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
      ...
    });

    return false;       
});
```

Comment: THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! This is the third thread and you answered it the easiest! I think it was how i was asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

Factor it out into a variable

```
var Target;
$("#txtrform").submit(function(){

    $.post(Target, $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        $("#col3").load('/include/txtrpbox/feed.php');
        $('input#txtrinput').val('');
    });

    return false;       
});

Target = '/include/1.php';

//submit now will go to 1.php

Target = '/include/2.php';
//submit now will go to 1.php
```

Comment: Nice. But for my platform, the first answer is simpler being that I'd have too many targets.